# React with React-Router works on localhost, but after deploying on cPanel fails to fetch api call

Tags: reactjs, deployment, react-router, fetch-api

I have searched for a few hours now found no working solution. I followed this guide

https://dev.to/crishanks/deploy-host-your-react-app-with-cpanel-in-under-5-minutes-4mf6

and everything works fine,
except for when I go into a react router path.

It doesn't just fail or return 404, it shows TypeError (basically API returning null or undefined)

The same route with the same API call works perfectly on localhost:3000.

1. I ran npm run build and copied all the contents onto cPanel file manager
2. Went to my domain and everything was working until I clicked into a react router route that has api fetching which works in localhost

```
<div>
                <Header />
                <Segment placeholder style={{marginTop: "2rem"}}>

                <Grid celled>
                    <Grid.Row>
                    <Grid.Column width={4}>
                        <Image src={`${this.props.config.images.secure_base_url}original${this.props.movieDetails.poster_path}`} wrapped ui />
                    </Grid.Column>
                    <Grid.Column width={12}>
                    <div className="carousel-container">
                            <div className="swiper-container">
                                <h2 className="swiper-container__title">Cast</h2>
                                <div className="swiper-wrapper">
                                    {this.props.movieCredits.cast.map(cast => {
                                        return (
                                        <div key={cast.cast_id} className="swiper-slide">
                                            <Link>
                                                {cast.profile_path ? <img className="swiper-slide__image" src={`${this.props.config.images.secure_base_url}w154${cast.profile_path}`} alt={cast.profile_path}/> : <img className="swiper-slide__image" src={placeholder} />}
                                                <p className="swiper-slide__title">{cast.name}</p>
                                                <p className="swiper-slide__details">as</p>
                                                <p className="swiper-slide__details">{cast.character}</p>
                                            </Link>
                                        </div>
                                        );
                                    })}
                                </div>
```

it fails at the part where i use this.props.movieCredits.cast.map to iterate over fetched api call data. Note that the information inside this.props.movieCredits was called in the very same component as shown above,

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        config: state.PostMDBConfig,
        apiKey: state.PostMDBConfig.apiKey,
        moviesPopular: state.postMoviePopular,
        tvPopular: state.postTVPopular,
        itemType: state.setItemType.itemType,
        movieGenres: state.getMovieGenre,
        tvGenres: state.getTVGenre,
        movieDetails: state.getMovieDetails,
        movieCredits: state.getMovieCredits,
        movieReviews: state.getMovieReviews,
        movieVideos: state.getMovieVideos
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        getMovieDetails: url => dispatch(getMovieDetails(url)),
        getMovieCredits: url => dispatch(getMovieCredits(url)),
        getMovieReviews: url => dispatch(getMovieReviews(url)),
        getMovieVideos: url => dispatch(getMovieVideos(url))
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ItemDetails);
```

Below is how I fetched the data

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchData(this.props.match.params.id);
    }


    fetchData(id, type = this.props.match.params.type) {
        switch(type){
            case 'movie':
                this.props.getMovieDetails(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id}?api_key=${this.props.apiKey}&language=en-US`)
                this.props.getMovieCredits(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id}/credits?api_key=${this.props.apiKey}`)
                this.props.getMovieReviews(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id}/reviews?api_key=${this.props.apiKey}&language=en-US&page=1`)
                this.props.getMovieVideos(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id}/videos?api_key=${this.props.apiKey}&language=en-US`)
                break;
            case 'tv':
                break;
            case 'people':
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, sorry about such a hassle.

**EDIT!!! TLDR + IMPORTANT EDIT**

After taking a break I think I've found the reason, being that this.match.params.id is not working, the question should be, *how to get params from url when deployed*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this.match.params is not working, which causes the API fetch error, will be looking into a workaround for this.

**EDIT**

Solution ended up being using a different lifecycle method, not sure why it works in localhost but componentWillMount used instead fixed the problem of fetch not being fetched.